# Flexible time selection

Tags: r, time

I'm having transaction data of multiple customers, such that each data point contain the `Time` which the transaction occured.

Now, when I'm getting new data point I want to subset my data for that specific customer with flexible 'hour' selection.

Here is an example `df`:

```
Cust_id    Date           Time 
1               5/1/17       03:12:22       
1               6/1/17       23:45:17
1               6/1/17       21:55:45
```

Assume my new data point belong to `Cust_id=1` and occured in `02:33:10`. Also assume that I want to subset all the transactions of this customer which took place in the range of *+- 3 hours*-regardless the day they occured. In my examle I should subset the first two rows.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way via base R,

```
p1 <- '02:33:10'
d1$Time <- format(strptime(d1$Time, format="%H:%M:%S"), format = "%H:%M:%S")

i1 <- format(strptime(p1, format="%H:%M:%S")+3*60*60, format = "%H:%M:%S")
i2 <- format(strptime(p1, format="%H:%M:%S")-3*60*60, format = "%H:%M:%S")

d1[d1$Time >= i2 | d1$Time <= i1,]

#  Cust_id   Date     Time
#1       1 5/1/17 03:12:22
#2       1 6/1/17 23:45:17
```